# How to print exception errors and trace tacks in a file when there's an error in my code?

Tags: python, error-handling

I want that whenever an error is raised in my code, `traceback.print_exception()` execute so I can have any errors in a file to check... Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try wrapping your code in a try/except block, and call the function in the except. It might look like this:

```
try:
    # Your code here
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exception(e)
```

Comment: I wanted to find another solution than this, but I guess this is the best I can find. Also, `traceback.print_exception(e)` returned `NoneType : None`, so I used instead `traceback.print_exception(*sys.exc_info(), file=file_here`. Thank you !